# Using Curves with tubeGeometry

Tags: three.js

I would like to create a curve using predefined points and use them to create a tubeGeometry. I am really confused about what is going on in some examples and the documentation is very lacking.

I can get the the tubegeometry to work if I use a spline curve, but this creates errors in coloring the points [that I can't seem to get answers to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064165/three-js-tubegeometry-and-and-splinecurve).

I think that what I need to do is create a curve with my predefined points and then send those points as a path to the tubeGeometry function. However, whenever I create a curve using the predefined points, I get the error the "getTangentAt is not a function."

I find the examples to be very confusing. For example, the one [here](https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Graphulus-Curve.html) uses this method to create the points sent to tubeGeometry:

```
THREE.Curve.create( 
    function() {},
    function(t) 
    {
        // default:    0 < t < 1
        //    want: tMin < t < tMax
        t = t * tRange + tMin;
        return new THREE.Vector3(xFunc(t), yFunc(t), zFunc(t)).multiplyScalar(1);
    }
```

This method creates the previous mentioned errors whenever I use it. I also don't understand where the inputs to this method are defined or really what the heck is going on there.

Can someone simply explain to me how to take an array of Three.Vector3s and use them to create a tubeGeometry without using a spline curve? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need use [SplineCurve3](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Curves/SplineCurve3) to interpolation array of point to curve: http://jsfiddle.net/dqej00sr/1/

```
var curve = new THREE.SplineCurve3( [
    new THREE.Vector3( -10, 0, 10 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( -5, 5, 5 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 5, -5, 5 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 10 )
] );
```

Comment: Within the question above I note that I can get it to work with SplineCurve3, but that there are coloring problems. That's what I am trying to solve.